# prove that the fucntion f(x)=(1-x)/(1+x) is uniformly is continuous [0,infinity).

Tags: real-analysis

let ε>0  there is δ>0 such that |f(x)-f(y)|<ε

let |y-x|<δ and |1-x|=2 and |1-y|=2 and let δ<2ε

|(1-x)/(1+x)-(1-y)/(1-y)|<2(y-x)/(1+x)(1+y)|=δ/2<ε

is this the way to do it?

Comment: Also check the M.SE guidelines on formatting equations here : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Your steps are correct in showing that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \left|\frac{2(y-x)}{(1+x)(1+y)}\right|.$$

You do not want to restrict $x$ and $y$ by taking $|1-x|= 2$ and $|1-y| = 2.$

Note that for all $x,y \geqslant 0$

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \frac{2|y-x|}{(1+x)(1+y)}\leqslant 2|y-x|.$$

Hence, for all $x,y \in [0,\infty)$ with $|x-y| < \delta = \epsilon/2$ , then we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

However, the function $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(-1,\infty)$.

Consider the sequences $x_n = -1+1/n$ and $y_n = -1 + 1/2n$.  Then as $n \to \infty,$

$$|x_n - y_n| = \frac1{2n} \to 0,$$

but

$$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| = \frac{2 \frac1{2n}}{\frac1{2n^2}}= \frac{n}{2} \to \infty.$$

Comment: ok thank you another question is that this function is not uniformly continuous on (-1,infinity).how do i do this ? is it the same way .wat would be different?

Comment: You're welcome -- I'll add to the answer.

Comment: In that case I show above there are sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $(-1,\infty)$ that get arbitrarily close but for which $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|$ gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: Your function goes to $\infty$ near $-1$. Write your uniform continuity inequality between $0$ and $x \to -1$ and you will get a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

You're in a particular case where $||f'||_{\infty}$ is bounded on your domain (easy to check).

This implies that $f$ is Lipschitz on the domain (with $||f'||_{\infty}$ being a Lipschitz factor)

Which in turns implies that $f$ is uniform. continuous (actually you can skip the Lipschitz part and just use the mean value theorem).